# ConTeXt system font search path

Tags: fonts, luatex, context, context-mkiv

I read from the official manual (http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Fonts_in_LuaTex#How_LuaTeX_handles_system_fonts)
that I need to `export OSFONTDIR="/usr/local/share/fonts;$HOME/.fonts"` to specify where the fonts should be looked for. However, it will only search `fonts` and `.fonts`. If I have fonts in the sub directories of these two, they won't be discovered. I find it inconvenient.

Is it possible to make it search the subfolders?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx. Font searching by LuaTeX in this regard is format-neutral: the search path is an engine thing. I've altered the tags to reflect that.

Answer (score 5):

Like other TeX-related environmental variables, controlling `OSFONTDIR` requires understanding how variables are [expanded by `kpathsea`](http://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-550007.1). The key is to know that `//` (two consecutive `/` chars) is treated as a 'recursive' marker. Thus what you want is

```
export OSFONTDIR="/usr/local/share/fonts//;$HOME/.fonts//"
```

Before you alter this value, I'd be tempted to check the current setting with

```
kpsewhich --var-value=OSFONTDIR
```

as it may already be correct.

Comment: I'm currently using my Windows system (TL2014) which reports `C:/Windows/fonts//` from `kpsewhich --var-value=OSFONTDIR`, which would be 'right', so I'd be cautious and check the value before making any changes.

Comment: Note that ConTeXt separates kpsewhich variables for MkII (which are defined in `texmf.cnf`) from those for MkIV (which are defined in `texmfcnf.lua`). To search for the variables in `texmfcnf.lua`, you need to use: `mtxrun --expand-var OSFONTDIR`.

Answer (score 1):

run

```
luaotfload-tool -fuvvv --log=stdout
```

and it shows you where fonts are searched

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how or if you can do this in your TeX system, so this is just a partial answer. You can do something like (the syntax on your system might be different)

```
for d in $HOME/.fonts/*/; do
    OSFONTDIR+=":$d"
done
```

to recursively add all subdirectories of $HOME/.fonts to OSFONTDIR.